# How to buffer multiple open files with Textwrangler?

Tags: textwrangler

I know that Textwrangler can do this, but I messed up my preferences folder in OSX yosemite and had to reset some things.
I have multiple files opened and viewable within the gutter of one window.
I used to be able to switch between documents without being prompted to save or discard changes, now I cannot.
I also cannot switch between recent documents with "option"+"command"+"left or right bracket", I assume because things are saved and flushed in switching from one document to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your self in the future. I know right!
If you choose to open the folder containing all of these documents, they won't be buffered properly.
If you instead open the files by either selecting them individually from the "open file dialog" or select multiple files at once from the same dialog, they will open fully buffered as you would expect. HTH
In case you were wondering, the future is very similar to the nineties, but with worse drugs.